# Google Colabでスクレイピングの設定準備ができません

Tags: google-colaboratory, chromedriver

スクレイピングの勉強をしようと「いまにゅのプログラミング塾」の「Webスクレイピング超入門」を見ています。M1 MacでGoogle Colabを使っています。
selenium はインストールできたみたいなのですが、chromedriver がいろいろやってみてもインストールできません。

```
!brew install chromedriver
```

と打っても、

```
/bin/bash: brew: command not found
```

と出てしまい、解決方法が見つかりません。

それで、Webからダウンロードしようと思い、Webのchromedriverのサイトから「chromedriver_mac64_m1.zip」をダウンロードし、ファイルを実行しようとしましたが、「“chromedriver”は、開発元が未確認のため開けません。」というメッセージが出てしまいます。

この問題を解決する方法か、スクレイピングを勉強する他の方法等あれば教えていただけたら大変うれしいです。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

追記２２０８２２：
アドバイスを受けて、もう一度やってみたところ、seleniumのインストールのときにすでにエラーが出ていることにも気がつきました。
その下に　successfully とも書いてあるので、エラーを見落としていました。
次のようになります。
これは、seleniumuは正常にインストールされていないということでしょうか。

```
!pip install selenium

Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Collecting selenium
  Downloading selenium-4.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (985 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 985 kB 11.3 MB/s 
Collecting urllib3[socks]~=1.26
  Downloading urllib3-1.26.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (139 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 139 kB 52.0 MB/s 
Collecting trio-websocket~=0.9
  Downloading trio_websocket-0.9.2-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting trio~=0.17
  Downloading trio-0.21.0-py3-none-any.whl (358 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 358 kB 45.1 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2021.10.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from selenium) (2022.6.15)
Requirement already satisfied: sortedcontainers in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from trio~=0.17->selenium) (2.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from trio~=0.17->selenium) (2.10)
Collecting sniffio
  Downloading sniffio-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=19.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from trio~=0.17->selenium) (22.1.0)
Collecting outcome
  Downloading outcome-1.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.7 kB)
Collecting async-generator>=1.9
  Downloading async_generator-1.10-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting wsproto>=0.14
  Downloading wsproto-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: PySocks!=1.5.7,<2.0,>=1.5.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from urllib3[socks]~=1.26->selenium) (1.7.1)
Collecting h11<1,>=0.9.0
  Downloading h11-0.13.0-py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 58 kB 7.7 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from h11<1,>=0.9.0->wsproto>=0.14->trio-websocket~=0.9->selenium) (4.1.1)
Installing collected packages: sniffio, outcome, h11, async-generator, wsproto, urllib3, trio, trio-websocket, selenium
  Attempting uninstall: urllib3
    Found existing installation: urllib3 1.24.3
    Uninstalling urllib3-1.24.3:
      Successfully uninstalled urllib3-1.24.3
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
requests 2.23.0 requires urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1, but you have urllib3 1.26.11 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed async-generator-1.10 h11-0.13.0 outcome-1.2.0 selenium-4.4.3 sniffio-1.2.0 trio-0.21.0 trio-websocket-0.9.2 urllib3-1.26.11 wsproto-1.1.0
```

Comment: seleniumを使いたいのはMacですか？GoogleColaboratoryですか？ Macでの操作とGoogleColaboratoryでの操作を混同されていませんか？ GoogleColaboratoryでスクレイピングしたいのであれば、それ用のコードが必要ですので"GoogleColaboratory selenium"等で検索していただきコードを書きましょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。はい、すごく混同しています！違うということを教えていただいて大変ありがとうございます。Google Colaboratoryでやる方向で行きたいと思います。

Comment: Google Colab 環境でやるのであれば、Mac に関する記述は省いた方が混乱が少なくなります。タイトル等も含めていま一度見直してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

初心者であれば手元のPC(Mac)でスクレイピングを勉強するか、GoogleColaboratoryでスクレイピングを勉強するかどちらかに決めて始めた方が良いかと思います。（慣れたら両方するのは問題ありませんが、最初に両方でやると混乱するかと思います。）

【GoogleColaboratoryの場合】
GoogleColaboratoryのOSはlinuxかと思います。(私の場合はUbuntu 18.04.6 LTSでした。）
下記でスクレイピングの下準備は出来るかと思います。

```
# Seleniumインストール
!pip install selenium
# chromedriverインストール
!apt update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
```

あとは[GoogleColaboratoryでchromedriverを利用する(2021年9月版)](https://i-doctor.sakura.ne.jp/font/?p=46745)などを参考に動作確認いただきコードを書かれると良いかと思います。

---

＜追記＞
質問の「動画」とはこちら（https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VRFfAeW30qE） でしょうか？ 講師の方はローカルのMacをお使いのようですね。動画と全く同じことをしたいのであればローカルのMacで実施されるのが良いかと思います。